# What is the proper way to return http status code from service class in a Rest based java web application?

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, restful-architecture

In restfull architecture , the service end points need to return http status code which can vary from 100 to 600. So i use Response to do this from Rest API class. But to send exact status code and message in response i make service class to return me response object with proper status code and message. Is this proper way ? Can service class return Response object (JAX-RS class)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [javax.ws.rs.core.Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html)

Here is an example

```
@GET
@Path("cities")
public Response getCities() {

    List<City> cities = null;
    try{
        cities = commonDelegate.getCities();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).entity("no city found").build(); // return 204
    }

    return Response.ok().entity(cities).build(); return 200

}
```

Comment: Hi but in your solution you have traced all exception to Status code No content found.There can be multiple reasons for exception and status code should be corresponding

Comment: Its just a sample for usage you can check for multiple conditions and return corresponding responses [See Response.Status](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html)

Comment: I agree but many times exception cannot give us freedom to express exact status code to send.